# Invalid prop 'component' when using redux-react with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

When using `connect` from react-redux in my case react router does not see my react component as a valid component. And there is a warning: *Failed propType: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `Route`*

**`index.js`**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import plattformApp from './reducers'

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var Main = require('./components/Main');

let store = createStore(plattformApp)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
        </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

**`Main.js`**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Link = ReactRouter.Link;
var KNGui = require("../components/KNGui");
var Search = require("../components/Search");

var Main = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
  }
});

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { test: state }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now `var Main` contains full module.

To access component you need either

```
var Main = require('./components/Main').default;
```

or

```
import Main from './components/Main';
```

to get component.